# How to put centered button below 2 linear layouts in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout

My goal is to have 2 columns with an edittext and few buttons, but I need a button in the bottom of the screen which would need to confirm the values. I cant get it to the bottom of the screen and to make it centered.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etWe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
        android:hint="@string/We"/>
    

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etThey"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
        android:hint="@string/They"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you consider using ConstraintLayout?

Comment: Yes, but I am unsure on how to make two columns using that layout. I am very new to android programming.

Comment: look at the example I wrote below, you can continue from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Confirm"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/col1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/col2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etWe"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="We"
            android:inputType="numberSigned" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/col2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/col1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etThey"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="They"
            android:inputType="numberSigned" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

it will generate the following layout:
[image]

Comment: no problem, please accept the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

This **XML** layout will help you

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etWe"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberSigned"
            android:hint="@string/We"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etThey"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberSigned"
            android:hint="@string/They"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In my opinion use `RelativeLayout`

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```